# Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, openweathermap

I'm getting this exception error when using the OpenWeatherMap API. I'm just trying to get the *result* to be an JSONObject, but *null* keeps coming up.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // What's coming in as result...
        // Printed to the console...
        // null{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear",
        // "description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],...}


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            Log.i("Weather Info", weatherInfo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
```

The JSON data comes in fine but all I want is it to become a JSONObject but the null part is catching. Any Ideas why that might be happening?

Also from the site the `JSON Response` coming in is:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],.....}
```

How come that doesn't have null at the start? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `weather` is jsonArray in your response you can not use `getString` on it.

Comment: I have same problem before this guy helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127581/8582710

Comment: Try this and up vote his answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127581/8582710

Comment: Try this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138888/10121512

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the data you receive **weather** is a JSONArray.

Try this :

```
 String json = "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-0.13,\"lat\":51.51},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01d\"}],.....}";

try{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray weather = jo.getJSONArray("weather");
    for(int i = 0;i < weather.length(); i++){
        JSONObject w = weather.getJSONObject(i);
        String main = w.getString("main");
        String description = w.getString("description");
        //...
    }
}catch (Exception e){

}
```

As you said if the result returned by the server start with `null` you will have this exception `org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

This is because this result is not a valid JSON content.

If you really receive this invalid content from the server a workaround can be to remove the `null` before parsing the JSON.

```
String crappyPrefix = "null";

if(result.startsWith(crappyPrefix)){
    result = result.substring(crappyPrefix.length(), result.length());
}
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still getting the error _Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject_ . It just doesn't seem to want to take the JSON data coming in. The site I'm getting it from doesn't have null at the very start, but when I get it in the _result_ it does. Does that matter?

Comment: That's really interesting actually! Thanks for explaining that :). But I don't want to use a hard coded String as I'm trying to learn how to do it from an API. The newest Update looks really clever. I keep forgetting about string manipulation. I'll give that a go! Thank you.

Comment: @Nirekin for handling null object first i have to remove null from that result...no other way to handle that

Answer (score 5):

Try This (worked for me).. I was having same problem

```
public class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String >{

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =null;
        URL url;


String resultString="";  <------- instead of setting it to null


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                int data = isr.read();
                while(data != -1){
                    char ch = (char) data;
                    resultString += ch;
                    data = isr.read();

                }
                return resultString;



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

some times the problem is your response is null, but you expect a JSONObject.
its bettter to resolve it in server side.if you can not edit server side code, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585701/8183629) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24566878/8183629) may be useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String main =object.getString("main");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is use of .isNull

```
if(result.has('objectName') && !result.isNull('objectName'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**The error means that your JSON is not valid** probabaly

You can test your JSON format [here](http://jsonprettyprint.com).

But the problem in your code is that you are trying to use getString() here

```
String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
```

While weather is actually JSONArray, if you want it as string use

```
String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Member Variables are initialized by default,
in case of String it gets initialized as `null`
ie. writing `String xyz;` is equivalent `String xyz=null;`
and when we concatenate this null string to another string, java compiler make null value a string
ie. `xyz=xyz+"abc"; //would result as nullabc`

That is what's happening to your JSON data, the data you're getting as the string is working fine but as you put it as a JSON object it returns the exception

`"Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject"` because it treats that as a null value.

1. The best thing to do initialize string as an empty string ie.
   `String xyz="";`
2. Or you may either remove that null at the beginning of the string as

   if(result.startsWith("null")){
   result = result.substring("null".length(), result.length());
   }
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

Answer (score -1):

try this below code , it's working for me.

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject weatherUrlObject =jParser.getJSONFromUrl(weatherUrl);
 try {
        JSONArray weather = weatherUrlObject.getJSONArray("weather");
        WeatherNow.setWeather_id(weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("id").toString());
        WeatherNow.setWeather_main(weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("main").toString());
        WeatherNow.setWeather_description(weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("description").toString());
        WeatherNow.setWeather_icon(weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("icon").toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

JSONPaser Class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

WeatherNow is my Getter-Setter method .

Comment: What is `JSONParser` and `WeatherNow`? dont post anything without any explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm trying to get the _result_ coming into the method to become the JSONObject first but thats where the issue is coming.

Comment: String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

replace : 

JSONArray weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");