# How do i get data from null JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, exception

This is my first Question on StackOverflow, So sorry for bad representation of the question.

Here is Json in logcat :

```
I/Result is: null{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String weather,id,result;

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int data = inputStreamReader.read();

                while(data != -1){
                    char count = (char) data;
                    result += count;
                    data = inputStreamReader.read();
                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

           try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                 String res = jsonObject.getString("coord");

                Log.i("Result is ",res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1");

    }
}
```

Here is Exception:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type
>   org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Not able to understand title How do i get data from null JSONObject?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid due to `null` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Initialize** your result string with empty

```
String result="";
```

Your result String is class variable and all String are by default initialize with **`=null`** value

below line add to **`null+yourResponse`**

```
 result += count;
```