# Detect age of network need for Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-wifi, telephonymanager

I m creating an app using Google Maps Geolocation API that will get the location of user from Network.  Google Maps Geolocation API have some attribute to send in url to get the proper output from Google. My Problem is

1. Cell tower objects - **age** 
   for reference yu can check here [Cell tower objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#cell_tower_object)
2. WiFi access point objects - **age , channel , signalToNoiseRatio**
   for reference you can check here [WiFi access point object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#wifi_access_point_object)

i tried TelePhonyManager and Wifi ScaneResult(), but do not able to get these value

if someone know or access Google Maps Geolocation API, Please make suggestion so i will pass these value into Google Map API to get best Result

waiting for response 
thanks

Comment: `TelePhonyManager` is a part of the Android SDK, the `Cell tower objects` and `WiFi access point objects` are parts of the Google Maps Javascript web service. So you can perform network request to get those Objects(for example, `asyncTask`) in your Android application, and parse the JSON results from API response, then use the result to update your mapView. Sample request:  `URL requestUrl = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" + &key=" + API_KEY);`

Comment: sorry for late reply, i got your point and i started working on it , it will be helpful if you provide any example how to send request, i m not able to value of Cell tower and Wifi Access in url via Json, Please provide example it will help me @ztan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` to do the network request.

Sample Code:

```
  private class GetGeolocationTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";

            try {
                // 1. create HttpClient
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY");

                String json = "";

                // 3. build jsonObject
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.accumulate("homeMobileCountryCode", 310);
                jsonObject.accumulate("homeMobileNetworkCode", 410);
                jsonObject.accumulate("radioType", "gsm");
                jsonObject.accumulate("carrier", "vodafone");

                JSONArray cellTowersArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject cellTowerObject = new JSONObject();
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("cellId", 42);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("locationAreaCode", 415);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("mobileCountryCode", 310);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("mobileNetworkCode", 410);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("age", 0);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("signalStrength", -60);
                cellTowerObject.accumulate("timingAdvance", 15);
                cellTowersArray.put(cellTowerObject);
                jsonObject.accumulate("cellTowers", cellTowersArray);

                JSONArray wifiAccessPointsArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject wifiAccessPointObject = new JSONObject();
                wifiAccessPointObject.accumulate("macAddress", "01:23:45:67:89:AB");
                wifiAccessPointObject.accumulate("age", 0);
                wifiAccessPointObject.accumulate("channel", 11);
                wifiAccessPointObject.accumulate("signalToNoiseRatio", 40);
                wifiAccessPointsArray.put(wifiAccessPointObject);
                jsonObject.accumulate("wifiAccessPoints", wifiAccessPointsArray);

                // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                json = jsonObject.toString();


                // 5. set json to StringEntity
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

                // 6. set httpPost Entity
                httpPost.setEntity(se);

                // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                // 9. receive response as inputStream
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if(inputStream != null)
                    result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                else
                    result = "Did not work";
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                logException(e);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                logException(e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logException(e);
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
          String line = "";
          String result = "";
          while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
              result += line;

          inputStream.close();
          return result;
    }
```

You can call this AsyncTask in your activity like this:

```
GetGeolocationTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetGeolocationTask();
getGeolocationTask.execute();
```

You can also read [this tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/) for detailed information about how to put JSON in request body.

Or, you can use [Google Volley](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20valley&oq=google%20valley&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2865j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20volley) library to do your network request, sample request can be found in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23221199/4195406).