# How to send data to server in android? (Beginner)

Tags: android, json, data-transfer

I have been trying to send JSON data to the server. However, my efforts have failed since **NameValuePair** is deprecated. And okHttp is giving some error like okie.string not found on library classpath. Does anyone know about it?. Please suggest me some other techniques. I tried a lot of Google however, the articles did not help since the articles were too old.

Any links or examples will definitely help.

Comment: This question and answer will help you a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley

Comment: Use a higher level library such as Retrofit or Volley

Comment: Try use Volley or Picasso. They do lot of work for you. They are better in performance also. I never try picasso. Volley link: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: I tried Picassio. Its good for images. I dont like Volley because its complex. I would like to go with Retrofit.

Comment: I did a project sending json data, I'm looking for it, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @JoseteManu ok Josete

Comment: Can you try send the json using postman Chrome? I'm writting my code on the response :D but to know if all working on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use retrofit for this. [Retrofit Update](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is what I did, i will write my own HttpRequest library, not default one. You have to do many changes if you want to use this code, but to guide i think is good, later i write the code better.

First thing you have to jsonify your data on android in this way:

```
private JSONObject jsonifyData() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        // first we begin with array form
        jsonArray.put(location.getLongitude());
        jsonArray.put(location.getLatitude());

        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
        mainObject.put(LOC,jsonArray);

        // here we put the rest of the data
        for ( String loc_key : location.getKeys())
            mainObject.put(loc_key, location.getParam(loc_key));

        for ( String key : ApplicationData.commercial_keys) {
            if ( !key.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationData.SERIAL) && comercial.containsKey(key))
                mainObject.put(key, comercial.get(key));
        }

        mainObject.put(API_DEVICE, t_device);
        mainObject.put(API_SCOPE, t_scope);
        mainObject.put(API_OS, API_ANDROID);

        String ip = "0.0.0.0";

        mainObject.put(API_IP, ip); // IP de salida del sitio

        return mainObject;
    }
```

I created this method for that job. I think there is no dificult to to this job, due time a put my own conversions, but a bit modify put yours.

Then, when you have a json format, have to put headers and send data:

```
try {
                JSONObject data = jsonifyData();
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString());

                String[] HEAD = {"Content-Type"};

                HashMap<String, String> cabeceras = new HashMap<>();
                cabeceras.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                // you can ignore much of this
                HttpRequest register = new HttpRequest(
                        'your_url',
                        null
                );
                register.setMethod("POST", 1);
                register.setHeaders(HEAD, cabeceras);
                register.setQuery(data.toString());

                register.start();
                register.join();

                upload_data = true;

            } catch (JSONException | MalformedURLException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

If you see, I use HttpRequest, it isn't the default one!! I created one with the same name, this is the code of the POST:

```
private JSONObject POST() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject response = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    InputStreamReader in = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod(POST);

        for (String KEY : KEYS) conn.setRequestProperty(KEY, headers.get(KEY));

        conn.connect();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(postParameters);
        Log.d("HttpRequest--->","DATA TO SEND: "+postParameters);
        out.close();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
                buffer.append('\r');
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

            in.close();
            response = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: I guess I will go with Retrofit. So much code is sorta difficult to maintain.