# Android Volley request - send object to Spring boot java web service

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, android-volley

I have some custom `POJO`:

```
class CustomClass {
    int x;
    String str;
    SecondCustomClass obj;  //indicate it's not class of simple types  
    //etc...
}
```

I want to send instance of him from `Android` (**Volley library**) client to web service running on `Spring-boot` java application. Currently I know how to send data with `URL` params and return to client custom object. But I want also to send custom object.

Code in Android (I know that I need to use 3'rd parameter which is now `null` but I'm struggling get it work):

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    "BASE_URL?param1=param", 
    null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            CustomClass result = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), CustomClass.class);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }
);
volleyQueue.add(request);
```

> Code in server:

EDIT: The solution to receive pojo is using `@RequestBody`

```
@RequestMapping("/webmethod")
public CustomClass webmethod(@RequestParam(value="obj_param") @RequestBody CustomClass obj) {
    //work with obj
}
```

> What do I need to put in Android side to get it work?

Comment: you have to send the state of the POJO not instance of the POJO

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: just put the JSON object that contains the same name as the name of field in custom POJO

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Please see my edit. I found the solution for server side, but still don't know how to send from Android pojo in volley request.

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I mean if you know you can post as answer and receive repu if it's correct...

Comment: you have the problem is Request param right not at the time of response

Comment: I need from Android send request with object as parameter - not a url param. In response I don't have problems parsing the returned object. In server side I also know how to get and send objects, and how to get url params.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97778/discussion-between-maheshwar-ligade-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the JSON object inside the JSON object.Below is the sample. When you are request the Parameter with only one request.

This the Request JSON

```
  {
    "x":10,
     "str":"MyName",
     "SecondCustomClass":{
          "id":10,
           "title":"make it eassy"
        }  
   }
```

This is the post parameter request from Android. Try this way. 
For more details [please use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)