# How to parse the JSON data when it is switch case

Tags: android

I am new to android development I want parse the JSON Data, I want get response from server by posting this below JSON data

```
// login JSON
mtjson={
        "action":"login",
        "data"  :{
                "email":"ajit@globemoving.net",
                "password":"ajit@globemoving.net",
                "mobile":"9845031333"


            }
    }

// retrieve enquiry list JSON
mtjson={
        "action":"eq-list",
        "data"  :{
                "vid":"108"
            }
    }

// retrieve enquiry details JSON
mtjson={
        "action":"eq-details",
        "data"  :{
                "vid":"108",                    // vendor ID
                "eqid":"eq72873",                   // enquiry ID
                "state":"new"                   // state = new,quoted
            }
    }


// submit new bid for enquiry JSON
mtjson={
        "action":"bid",
        "data"  :{
                "vid":"108",                    // vendor ID
                "eqid":"eq72873",                   // enquiry ID
                "bid_amount":"5000",
                "mobile": "9876543623",
                "note":"dkjhdah"                
            }
    }
```

Hence please help with code with Httpurlconnection method. coz i am using new android studio apche.org is deprecated.

MainActivity

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler webreq = new ServiceHandler();
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();


        JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject j2=new JSONObject();

        try { j2.put("vid", "108");
            String e = j2.toString();
            j1.put("action", "eq-list");
            j1.put("data", e); }
        catch (JSONException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); }
       // String params = j1.toString();
       // Log.d("output", String.valueOf(j2));
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST, params);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        studentList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

        return null;`
```

Service Handler

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

//Constructor with no parameter
public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making web service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod) {
    return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod,
                                String params) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urladdress);

        DataInputStream input;

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);





        if (requestmethod == POST) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");



        } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }


        if (params != null) {

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            writer.write(result.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: which json structure is to be sent as request and which to be retrieved, explain elaborately.

Comment: mtjson={
        "action":"eq-list",
        "data"  :{
                "vid":"108"
            }
    }  this should be posted

Comment: // json structure data to post-{ "action":"eq-list", "data" :{ "vid":"108" } }                                                                              
  JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();  
  JSONObject j2=new JSONObject();
  try {
   j2.put("vid", "108"); 
   j1.put("action", "eq-list");
   j1.put("data", j2);
  } catch (JSONException e) {   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }                                                                                                  and to post request check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley

Comment: this should be placed in post req no..if (requestmethod == POST) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
 JSONObject j1=new JSONObject();JSONObject j2=new JSONObject();
   try { j2.put("vid", "108");  j1.put("action", "eq-list");            j1.put("data", j2):} catch (JSONException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
            } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            }

Comment: hi can get ur mail id so that i can send code...please guide me

Comment: @Mahalakshmi while sending it should be string not in object,  HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();  so please tell me how pass it?

Comment: convert object to string and try, posting code will help resolve your issue quicker

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I should *really* use a networking library to make it easier to send network requests, and parse the responses as objects in your model.

Have a look at:

- [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

  - based on [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

I can provide more examples if you'd like but the documentations linked above are sufficient IMO.

Cheers!