# How to put hash map with different number of values in Volley onResponse

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-volley

I need to do Volley POST method with this kind of body for onResponse method:

{"table":{"ma":1,"mb":2},"token":"access"}.

So basically I need HashMap called "params" that takes multiple key-value pairs as values for "table" key, and single value for"token" key, that goes inside Volley request.

I tried to do this,but it requires List for second argument for "token" value

```
    Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();

    // Hash map for "ma" 
    HashMap<String, String> maParams = new HashMap<>();
    maParams.put("ma", "1");

    Hash map for "mb"
    HashMap<String, String> mbParams= new HashMap<>();
    mbParams.put("mb", "2");

    // Table values
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(String.valueOf(maParams));
    values.add(String.valueOf(mbParams));

    params.put("table", beacons);
    params.put("token", "access");
```

Any ideas how I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require in your body actually looks like JSON. As I don't actually understand what you are trying to achieve with your code I would instead suggest that you take a look to famous JSON APIs such as [**`Jackson`**](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or give a try to **`JSONObject`** . You will easily find ways to build an object just like you asked `{"table":{"ma":1,"mb":2},"token":"access"}`.

If overkill for you then just write pure Java to achieve what you want: build a map of tokens (instead of 2 Maps + 1 List) and write a formatting method to put it like you want in your `params`. **Note**: as `{"ma":1,"mb":2}` is not double-quoted in your example then what `params` must look like is more certainly a simple `String` (and not any kind of Map!). Actually this is JSON..

**EDIT**: you are strongly advised to have a look to these posts:

- [How to send a POST request with JSON body using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079174/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-json-body-using-volley)
- [Android Volley POST Json to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442965/android-volley-post-json-to-server)
- [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)
- [How to send a POST request using volley with string body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body)

Which all look like possible duplicates..

Comment: Thanks bsaverino, what I basically want to do is to make HashMap out of that JSON file, to use it for Volley POST Request.

Comment: Edited my answer as Google and StackOverflow can already answer for me. All you need is quite common and just there.

Comment: And be careful to NOT mix up the parameters Map and your JSON objects (or body). This is not the same! `List<String>` as params values is not very common and sounds illegal to me. Parameters should remain a `Map<String,String>` somehow.