# What could be wrong with my Android Volley project?

Tags: android, android-volley

Good day people, I'm using Android Volley, version 1.1.1. The project runs swiftly when it's a GET request but as soon as I add the params and turn it to a POST request (like in all the examples I found all over the internet) it does not want to run and gives me three errors:

```
error no. 1" There is no applicable constructor to '(into, java.lang.String, com.vm.okone.MainActivity.(anonymous),com.vm.okone.MainActivity.(anonymous))', error no. 2 " method onResponse does not override method from its superclass, error no. 3 " method onErrorResponse does not override method from its superclass.
```

Here is my POST code

```
//TextView
final TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.serverResp);

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        //url
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.jsp";


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the response string.
                    mTextView.setText(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            }) {
            //adding parameters to the request
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", "asdf");
                params.put("email", "qwerty");
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Check this sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651360/4409113

Comment: It is still giving me the same errors and I'm starting to thing that its something to do with context but for now I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: That depends on where you are using those codes? That's strange because everything looks normal in my side.

Comment: Can you post your import statements at the top of your file?

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

Comment: Hmm nothing wrong with imports, you might have to post your actual logcat stacktrace to see what it's saying. Maybe you missed out something in your error description. Also the actual onCreate code snippet might reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

Volley Response class constructor is private, so you can't extend it. I tested your codes,no errors occurred, so maybe other issue existed.

Place codes in Oncreate() or other methods within MainActivity and try again.

**Edit**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        //url
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.jsp";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the response string.
                        mTextView.setText(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        }) {
            //adding parameters to the request
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", "asdf");
                params.put("email", "qwerty");
                return params;
            }
        };

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is placed on the onCreate() method which is in the MainActivity.