# In Android ,Volley , How to pass a single string Parameter and receive a string result?

Tags: android, android-studio, parameter-passing, android-volley

Want to send a single parameter and receive a string type result but it doesn't work.

I tested my RESTfull API with this Url in a browser and it works fine:

```
http://192.168.1.20:88/Home/testme?a=abc
```

But when want to use it in Android Studio(Java language) it does not work and the Exception message is null.
After reading some posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728092/android-volley-post-parameters), I''m confused should I use JSON type in sending?
If yes, why?

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.20:88/Home/testme";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        tVMessage.setText(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                              tVMessage.setText("That didn't work!"+error.getMessage());
                    }
        }){
            @Override
            protected  Map<String,String> getParams() {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("a","test value");
                return params;
            }

           @Override
            public  Map<String,String> getHeaders() {
               Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
               params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your url to be :

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.20:88/Home/testme?a=abc";
```

Because its a **GET** request, getParams() function only used in **POST** request

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a **GET** request not **POST**

So just change the URL to this

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.20:88/Home/testme?a=abc";
```

And change `Request.Method.POST` to `Request.Method.GET`