# Cannot Receive JSONobject on JSONObjectRequest using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

This is my code for requesting the JSONObject. While working with String request it worked perfectly but i need JSONObject.

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("request", "login");

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);

    String url="http://example.com/android/login.php";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,jsonObj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // response
                   // JSONObject json = JSONObject.toJson(response);
                   // Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Your ID is ."+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //Log.d("Response", response.toString());

                    Intent r = new Intent(Login.this,Cus_home.class);
                    startActivity(r);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );

    mRequestQueue.add(postRequest);
```

On checking the API output the output is :
 `[{"id":"77","type":"1"}]`

But after running the android code, I get this

```
Error.Response: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of
```

Any help help is really appreciated

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley ? It suggests using this syntax as follows: `final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"type\":\"example\"}");`

Comment: I am having issues receiving JsonObject. Not sure if that can help me

Comment: @SimonPhoenix JsonObject is from my input fields. Please suggest something more

Answer (score 0):

You are returning invalid JSON Object. You are returning a JSON String instead of object.

> JSON objects are written inside curly braces. e.g.
>   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}`

your onResonse method would look like this

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("response", response.optString("id") + " " +
                            response.optString("type"));

}
```

Comment: Yes I understood that. Now I get The out put as {"id":"77","type":"1"} , But even then I still get same error on Response.ErrorListener()

Comment: check my updated answer i have tested it. everything is working fine.