# Send data to server as json format using android Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I want to send data from android app to remote server in JSON format.
Below is my json format :-

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "ritva",
      "phone_no": "12345657890",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "jisa",
      "phone_no": "12345657890",
      "user_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "tithi",
      "phone_no": "12345657890",
      "user_id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can any one tell me how do I send this data using Volley?

Comment: create a pojo class add data.simple

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: the easiest way I can think is, convert the entire data to string. Create a new StringRequest() <- Volley method and use the GET method to append the data behind the URL eg `http://www.mytest.com/getdata.php?data=JSONDataHere`

Comment: Send the same way you send any normal data to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a volley request like bellow which takes method like `POST/GET`,
   `url`, `response & error` listener. And For sending your json override
   `getBody()` method in which pass the json you want to send.
2. Make a `RequestQueue` & add the request to it. You might start it by
   calling `start()`

**Try this :**

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://www.google.com";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // your response

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String your_string_json = ; // put your json
            return your_string_json.getBytes();
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    requestQueue.start();
```

**For more info see** [this](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Comment: Where is the getBody() method defined? I cannot see it in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1b4858087f25a8033c5136a96b750752b87e128c/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.java)

Comment: its the override method

Comment: of which class but? Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley
Check this link it will give you more prominent solution

Comment: using get body completely depends upon your requirement @GeetChoubey :) i have used volley in more than 5 projects but have never used this method. Preetika just gave a idea change the code according to your requirement.

Comment: @GeetChoubey getBody() is there in same class under String Request only

Answer (score 0):

For sending `JSON` type data you should make a `JSON` request using **volley**

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

     JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.POST, url, obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
requestQueue.start();
```

Where `object` is your `JSONObject` that you want to send. Ask if you want more clarification.

Mark this up if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add Volley and Gson Dependency into build.gradle:**

```
'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' 
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Note: If you have JSON data in String variable then just pass the String variable as third parameter in JsonObjectRequest.**(Go to Step 6)**

If you have JSON data in your classes then just pass the class in gson.toJson() of the third parameter of JsonObjectRequest.**(Go to Step 6)**

If you want to get the data in class then you need to create classes structure same as JSON data. **(Go to step 2)**

**2. Then create the POJO classes for the above JSON Structure using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/**

Example Shown in image:
[Red marks showing the changes needed to make on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKJN7.png)

Then you will get two classes as ContactsTop and Contact.
Note: ContactsTop is name provided at the time of creating POJO classes from jsonschema2pojo.com

**3. Add above generated classes into your project**

**4. Create Volley RequestQueue object and gson object.**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

**5. Then add above JSON data to POJO Classes.**

```
ContactsTop contactsTop=new ContactsTop();
List<Contact> contactList =new ArrayList();
Contact contact=new Contact();

contact.setPhoneNo("12345657890");
contact.setName("ritva");
contact.setUserId("1");

contactList.add(contact);
contactsTop.setContacts(contactList);
```

**6. Create JSONObject to call web service with your data.**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "www.your-web-service-url.com/sendContact.php", gson.toJson(contactsTop), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             Log.v("Volley:Response ", ""+response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.v("Volley:ERROR ", error.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });
```

**7. Add your jsonObjectRequest into requestQueue. (Don't forget to add this line. this is will add your request in RequestQueue and then only you will get JSON Response or Error from your Service). Don't forget to add INTERNET Permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

**Then you will get Response or Error from your Remote Service in android Log monitor.**