# android - how to send post to server using JsonArrayRequest volley?

Tags: php, android

How to send post from `JsonArrayRequest` volley to server php?

my code to connect to server:

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){
    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Comment: Please do some research before posting duplicate questions. This topic is covered extensively on SO. If you are facing specific problems regarding your code, post that as a question.

Comment: I trying some answer but no work and get error

Comment: So post what you are trying and what errors you are facing.