# how to create jsonObject for bellow Structure in java

Tags: android, json

```
     {
     "DATATABLE": [
      {
      "ENTITYID": "2",
      "USERID": "5897",
      "ORGID": "P01",
      "COMPID": "A0002",
      "IP": "0",
      "INDENT_NO": "0",
      "SERIAL": "1",
      "DOC_DT": "06/04/2017",
      "ITM_CD": "100000397",
      "QTY": "6",
      "RATE": "9",
      "FROM_LOC": "0",
      "REMARK": "Re",
      "REQ_DT": "06/04/2017",
      "ADD_SPEC": "Ass",
      "PROJECT": "0",
      "IND_TYPE": "R",
      "IND_CAT": "REV",
      "PURPOSE": "P"
     }
               ],
     "Mode": "I"
    }
```

How to create Json Object in java using above code
 please give me code. i searched on stack overflow for but i have not get json object code for same json formate

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: Use this tool: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code snippet.

```
class DATATABLE{
    String ENTITYID;
    .... define all fileds here.
}

class Data{
    List <'DATATABLE> list;
    String Mode;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43272560/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

Create JSON param like it and send this param with volley request

```
JSONObject paramObj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject();
Obj.put("ENTITYID", "2");
Obj.put("USERID", "2");

// and so on....

 // Now put obj into array
dataArray.put(0, Obj);

// put array and last value into paramObj
paramObj.put("DATATABLE", dataArray);
paramObj.put("Mode", "I");
```

Send "paramObj" JSONObject with volley request param.
And for More detail about how use volley with JSON param can fallow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) tutorials it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used volley to parse the above the json format.
Parse your  url for the below code.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.theme.androidvolley">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:name="AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AppController.Java

**
 * Created by root on 7/4/17.
 */

```
public class AppController  extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }
    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // json object response url
    //Parse your url 
    private String urlJsonObj = " // Parse your  url";
    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnMakeObjectRequest;
    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private TextView txtResponse;
    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;
    Activity mActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mActivity = MainActivity.this;
        btnMakeObjectRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);
        txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        btnMakeObjectRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // making json object request
                makeJsonObjectRequest();
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Method to make json object request where json response starts wtih {
     */
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        showpDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = response.getJSONArray("DATATABLE");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String ENTITYID = c.getString("ENTITYID");
                        String USERID = c.getString("USERID");
                        String ORGID = c.getString("ORGID");
                        String COMPID = c.getString("COMPID");
                        String IP = c.getString("IP");
                        String SERIAL = c.getString("SERIAL");
                        String DOC_DT = c.getString("DOC_DT");
                        String ITM_CD = c.getString("ITM_CD");
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        jsonResponse += "ENTITYID: " + ENTITYID + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "USERID: " + USERID + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "ORGID: " + ORGID + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "COMPID: " + COMPID + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "IP: " + IP + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "SERIAL: " + SERIAL + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "DOC_DT: " + DOC_DT + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "ITM_CD: " + ITM_CD + "\n\n";
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }
    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.theme.androidvolley.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnObjRequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Make JSON Object Request" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResponse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnObjRequest"
        android:layout_marginTop="40px"
        android:padding="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```