# Volley Parse Error Android

Tags: android, android-volley

Handle service call using volley library. Its working fine for jsonObject, jsonArray and String request but my application have one service different request and response. In this service have post params are Jsonobject, and return response is String.

I am trying many solution to handle response.but no one working. I am new android application developer.

post param and response:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }

}) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return getHeader();
    }
};

jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48, 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
VolleyRequest.volleyRequestInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Did you try with `StringRequest`?

Comment: Thanks for reply sripad. yes have try StringRequest but return server error

Comment: Similar ansewr to your solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31638943/4653447

Comment: If its a server error. Check at server side then :)

Comment: if i check in postman working fine

Comment: add your server code or the response from the post man

Comment: we are using magento framework for my ecommerce side.so megento have some default Apis.dont change anything this api

Comment: postmas response : "jbkyen4t3at987rg7u7dsecooo5gafhp"

Comment: Check your request obj, compare with your request in your postman client. I guess some difference might be breaking the server.

Comment: the same objects are sending

Comment: Are u understand my problem?

Comment: Post Parameter are json but api giving response format string. so how to handle in volley

Comment: post stack trace

Comment: @Saravanan.S Did you try using volley custom Request?

Comment: I am don't try customrequest

Answer (score 1):

Volley Parse error will occur in different scenarios

1. If you call post method as to get, and also get as post
2. You have tried to pass different payloads
3. Return values are different in types that you are expected

Use a custom request to solve this issue in normal cases example here:

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom

in your code.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

}

}) {
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

     Map<String,String> myHeader=new HashMap<>();
     myHeader.put("Accept","text");
    return myHeader;
}
};

 jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new 
 DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48, 
2,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
 VolleyRequest.volleyRequestInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue
(jsonObjectRequest);
```

also needs your 'params' value for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

Check on the response the URL returns the problem might be not the code but the URL response.
In my case Volley failed to parse my response because it did not understand the response from the URL.
hope this answer will help someone good luck :)