# Android Volley JsonObjectRequest onResponse how to allow JSONObject as NULL

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have the following lines:

```
Consumer<JSONObject> OnSuccess;  // Defined somewhere else...
JsonParameters = jsonParameters; // Defined somewhere else...
String targetUrl = BaseService.BuildUrl(BASE_TARGET_URL, TargetMethod);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (
            Request.Method.POST,
            targetUrl,
            JsonParameters,
            response -> {
                OnSuccess.accept(response);
            },
            error -> {
                Toast.makeText(BaseService.BaseContext, 
                      "ERROR: COMS NOT WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    )
};
```

In this specific case, I am reaching the server to obtain an object from the DB.
When the object on the server side exists, the code on java hits the method `OnSuccess`, however, when the server, simply returns a `null` object (there are no errors on the server, It is simply returning a `null` object, if this is the case) then my java code is hitting the "`onError`"....

But for me this is plain wrong, because I want the onError to just happen when there is really an error (or because the server is down, or the DB is down, or some exception along the way happens), NOT when the server returns a simply `null` object.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem in java ? I do not want to change the server to return me an empty object (not `null`)....

Thanks

Comment: but in case the server returns `null`, which is the content of the `error` variable?

Comment: @Lino Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: any feedback after the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Volley's `JsonObjectRequest` is specifically designed to handle JSON objects. In case the server returns `null` value then it is normal that the `onError` callback is invoked because, as you said in the comment, `null` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`.

My suggestion is to use a less strict Volley object request, like for instance `StringRequest`. When the `onSuccess` is hit and when the result is not `null` convert the resulting code into a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject jsonResp = new JSONObject(response);
OnSuccess.accept(jsonResp);
```

Conversely, when the response is `null`, then you can treat it as your needs (and of course avoid to create JSONObject as above)

Comment: In the end my solution was to use the StringRequest as you suggested.
My code was based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley/31638943#31638943